The article in "a salt on its tail"
I am looking for a rationale for the presence of the indefinite article in the following passage (with the phrase in question highlighted in bold):

Palmer was a 19th century English painter, largely self-taught, whose early landscapes were touched with a visionary quality influenced by William Blake. Palmer himself described them best when he said that they had "a curiousness in their beauty – a salt on their tails by which the imagination catches hold on them". Completed between 1826 and 1835 when Palmer was living in the Kent village of Shoreham, the watercolors and drawings from this period are exceedingly rare, numbering fewer than one hundred.

-- Jonathon Keats, excerpt from Forged: Why Fakes Are The Great Art Of Our Age
Several possibilities come to mind, the most likely seems to me to be that "salt on its tail" is a set phrase to a degree that justifies its nominalization. If so, are there other examples of such phenomena? If not, can anyone throw some light into the matter?

What effort have you made to answer this question for yourself? A simple Goolge of "salt tail" yields this Wikipedia article, which reads, in part, "Salting a bird's tail is a legendary superstition of Europe and America, and an English language idiom. The superstition is that sprinkling salt on a bird's tail will render the bird temporarily unable to fly, enabling its capture."

The presence of "a" before "salt on its tail" implies that there might conceivably be many different ways "by which the imagination catches hold", and that the "curiousness in their beauty" is merely one of these ways.

@PaulTanenbaum The question is a grammatical one. I give my hypothesis about the quoted usage. I fail to see what you're driving at.

So, that person at that time said a salt. It's just that way.

My point is that your question offers no evidence that you had made any effort to find the answer before posting. If I understand your first speculation, you hypothesized that salt on its tail is a set phrase. Confirming as much via Google would have been simple. That's what I was driving at; that and to provide you the explanation of the expression so you could work out why the author had chosen the indefinite article.

@PaulTanenbaum I was aware the "salt on its tail" superstition, if that is the gist of your problem with my question. It does not solve the issue, as far as I can see.

I think the indefinite article there expresses the idea that it's a figurative salt on their tails.

a curiousness is parallel to a salt... It had a curiousness — a salt on its tail...

Or maybe it’s a play on words... assault on its tail...

@TinfoilHat That's probably what Palmer intended. It was just poorly transcribed, perhaps by a third party.

Salt is not a mass noun to chemists: sodium chloride is just one among many.

@BrianDonovan  An imagination-enhancing salt on their tails. Cocaine?


Palmer himself described them best when he said that they had "a curiousness in their beauty – a salt on their tails by which the imagination catches hold on them".

This is correct. The author is referencing the (now, chiefly historical) joke/folk belief that birds can be caught by putting salt on their tail.
He is using "a salt on their tails" as an attribute to mean that the paintings have this particular attribute that delays the departure of the person who sees them.
Today, you could use the word "a glue" or "a stickiness" or "a captivation" and that is how they capture the imagination and delay the viewers departure.
Why is there an "a" with what is usually an uncountable noun? A/an = a type of

they had "a curiousness in their beauty – a salt on their tails by which the imagination catches hold on them"

they had "a curiousness in their beauty – an amount of some substance that causes immobilisation and through which the imagination [is able to catch/] catches hold on them"
From Wikipedia

Salting of a bird's tail has been used by analogy as an idiom for immobilizing someone since at least the 19th century, by writers such as Walter Scott,[3] Robert Burns,[2] Walter Lantz,[8] and John Phillips


Thanks. So just because "salt on its tail" is a set phrase, it's fine to use it with an article (as I've conjectured)?

salt, coffee, tea, flour as noncountables do NOT take an a, usually. A is not some.

Hmm... That is not quite the reason The reason is that the writer has made a figurative noun phrase from a known sentence/story.

@Lambie, the indefinite article is used here in the same way in which someone might say something like She has an innocence about her that is disarming.

@Greybeard OK. I still do not quite see the difference between your "noun phrase out of a known sentence/story" and my conjectured "nominalization of a set phrase".

@anemone - Ah! The word "nominalization" makes all the difference.

From the quote, it's not the viewer whose departure is prevented: the special quality of the works is pinning down a meaning or power in the work that would otherwise be elusive and would fade or disappear. A great work of art lingers in the imagination, it doesn't fade away or vanish. The quote talks about "the imagination catches hold on them" where the imagination is the viewer's and "them" is the paintings, not vice versa.

@anemone It's not insignificant that "a" was already used a few words earlier for "curiousness," and the following clause is meant to parallel it. Even though the clause has many words, it would be odd to use "the," following "a curiousness." Hopefully the goal is to understand this usage, not to interrogate it as valid or not, since Palmer already said it and is well out of the reach of our punishment! Is it recommendable to copy? Maybe not, especially centuries later.

@anemone Personally, if I felt compelled to nominalize thusly, I might add something like "... a sort of salt on their tails_," or maybe even if I were feeling wacky, to hyphenate ("a sort of salt-on-their-tails"). But either way, I think I would do better to sober up and start over entirely.

I don't disagree with Greybeard's etymology or semantic analysis, but the following may help explain the grammar.
A normal reading of 'have an X on their tails' would involve the verb have taking a noun phrase an X as a Direct Object and the preposition phrase on their tales as a Locative Complement. We can see this kind of construction in examples such as:

she had a poker in the fire
he had a hat on his head
they had a pizza in the oven

However, in Palmer's example, the structure is very different. The verb have here is taking a single noun phrase as a Direct Object. The noun phrase is a salt on their tales, where the indefinite article, a applies to the whole nominal salt on their tales. This nominal behaves idiomatically a bit like a compound noun here, referring to, as Greybeard describes, a particular kind of attribute or characteristic.

Many thanks. Does your first example work as intended though? I suppose the second and the third can be rephrased as "On his head, he had a hat" and "In the oven, they had a pizza" to witness the independence of the object from the complement. Would it work to say "In the fire, she had an iron"?

@anemone Probably not, actually. I meant it literally,  but of course it probably came to mind first because of the idiom. I'll change it.
